# Error while trying to reach sitemap.xml

Tags: php, sitemap

I get such an error  when trying to reach sitemap.xml
I generated xml sitemap file and put it in root folder on server but when I try to acces it I get following error:

```
   Warning: require_once(/home/europezone/html/inc/pages.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/europezone/html/index.php on line 44 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/europezone/html/inc/pages.inc.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/europezone/html/index.php on line 44
```

Comment: I suggest you forgot upload file /home/europezone/html/inc/pages.inc.php to server

Comment: I have uploaded this file and now I get no response from server whent only for europezone.ru/sitemap.xml

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/europezone/html/inc/functions.inc.php on line 64`
 - often it means wrong database credentials. Please, [read about debugging](http://phpfaq.ru/error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sitemap should have had `.php` format, the solution was to add .`php` to the end `sitemap.xml.php`